# A function accepting two stacks as parameters and return a Python list

Tags: python, stack

Please help me write a function to add numbers from two stacks by the position and return the result as a list.

Code here are operations on the stack:

```
stack_a = Stack()
stack_a.push(1)
stack_a.push(2)
stack_b = Stack()
stack_b.push(6)
stack_b.push(8)
result = add(stack_a , stack_b)
print(result)
```

and here is the definition of the Stack class

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self):
    self.items = []

  def is_empty(self):
    return self.items == []

  def push(self, item):
    self.items.append(item)

  def pop(self):
    return self.items.pop()

  def peek(self):
    return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

  def size(self):
    return len(self.items)
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
def add(first, second):
  return first.pop() + second.pop()
```

I got 10 which only accounts for addition of stack_a.push(2) and stack_a.push(10). Please help me improve on what I got so far.

Comment: You'll need a loop of some kind

Comment: What's should be in the list? What if the two stacks are different sizes? Is it OK to destroy (as in potentially remove all) the items in both stacks in the process of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will be the same, excluding the extra `add_all` function which i added. It pops last item of two stacks that you provide, adds them, and appends them in a list that you get as a result.

Note that the order in the returned list is last to first, like in your add function.

```
def add(first, second):
    return first.pop() + second.pop()

def add_all(first_stack, second_stack):
    """
    Pops last elements of two stacks and adds them,
    until all elements are added.

    Returns:
        list
    """

    returned_lst = []

    # Determine the how many items will be added.
    # (ensures that no errors are raised if two stacks have different size)
    number_of_items_to_be_added = min(first_stack.size()), second_stack.size())

    # If you are using Python 2.x use 'xrange' instead of 'range'
    for element in range(number_of_items_to_be_added):
        returned_lst.append(add(first_stack, second_stack))

    return returned_lst

stack_a = Stack()
stack_a.push(1)
stack_a.push(2)
stack_b = Stack()
stack_b.push(6)
stack_b.push(8)
stack_b.push(9)

result = add_all(stack_a, stack_b)
print(result)
```

Let me know if i misunderstood what you need, or if you need something more.

Comment: Technically you're breaking object-encapsulation by using `min(len(first_stack.items), len(second_stack.items))` instead of `min(first_stack.size(), second_stack.size())`. Directly accessing class internals like that makes code more likely to break, aka "fragile", if the implementation of `Stack` ever changes since it introduces an unnecessary dependency on the its (hidden) implementation.

Comment: @martineau What is `size()`?

Comment: It's the name of a method that `Stack` objects have which returns `len(self.items)`. It's at the end of the definition of `class Stack` in the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over the elements of the stack and as we see that the elements of the stack are stored in the `.items` , which is a list so we find out the length of the list and iterate over each index and add the corresponding elements.

If the length of both the stacks is unequal then it will iterate upto the length of the minimum of the two.

```
def add(first, second):
    answer = []
    for i in xrange(min(len(first.items), len(second.items))):
        answer.append(first.items[i]+second.items[i])
    return answer
```